# How to find the solution of $4u_x+8u_y-u=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

find the solution of the cauchy equation below

$4u_x+8u_y-u=1$

$u(x,3x)=cos(x)$

my attempt:

char. eq. is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{8}{4}=2$

$dy=2~dx$, $y=2x+k$

we can take $\xi=x$ and $\eta=y-2x$

$y=\eta+2\xi$

$w(\xi,\eta)=u(x,y)$

$u_x=w_\xi-2w_\eta$ and 
$u_y=w_\eta$
so the equation is $4(w_\xi-2w_\eta)+8w_\eta-w=1$

so $w=-\frac{1}{4}
e^{\frac{\xi}{4}
}e^{-\xi}+g(\eta) $ then 
$u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4}
e^{\frac{x}{4}
}e^{-x}+g(y-2x)$$\quad$$\quad$(*)

when we subsitute  $u(x,3x)=cos(x)=-\frac{1}{4} 
e^{\frac{x}{4}
}e^{-x}+g(x)$

$ g(x)=\frac{1}{4}
e^{\frac{-3x}{4}
}+cos(x)$ so the solution is $ u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4}
e^{\frac{-3x}{4}
}+\frac{1}{4}
e^{\frac{-3(y-2x)}{4}
}+cos(y-2x)$
isnt this approach correct?
edit2 : mistake was at (*) w(ξ,η)  had to equal to $g(η)e^{ξ/4}−1. $

Comment: Does your solution satisfy the differential equation and the boundary condition?

Comment: @JasonZimba sadly no. where is the mistake?

Comment: I think that $w(\xi,\eta)=c(\eta)e^{\xi/4}-1.$

Comment: @lyme, that is not a very polite edit. People are busy and have regular jobs. Also, since you know your solution to be incorrect, I think you should edit your question so that it no longer says "is this correct?".

Comment: @JasonZimba i didnt want to be rude.  didnt accuse or anything. I wrote "what is wrong with my question" because just wondered why noone got interested . But you are right, i should've deleted "is this  correct" part

Comment: @lyme thanks for the clarification. I did find your work hard to follow. Below is my solution process for this equation, I hope it is helpful.

Comment: @Cortizol thanks. you were right. My mistake was at that linear eq.'s calculation. JasonZimba Thank you too fo the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve $4 u_x + 8 u_y = u + 1$ with boundary condition $u(x,3x) = \cos x$, I solve the three ordinary differential equations
$$\frac{dx_r}{ds}=4 \\ \frac{dy_r}{ds}=8 \\ \frac{dz_r}{ds}=z + 1$$
with initial conditions
$$x_r(0) = r \\y_r(0) = 3r \\ z_r(0) = \cos r\,.$$
The solutions are 
$$x = 4s + r \\ y = 8s + 3r \\ z = (1+\cos r)e^s - 1\,.$$
Expressing $r$ and $s$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, we have $r = y - 2x$ and $s = \frac{3}{4}x - \frac{1}{4}y$, so that
$$z = u(x,y) = (1 + \cos{(y-2x)})e^{\frac{3}{4}x - \frac{1}{4}y} - 1\,.$$

Some good notes on this solution method may be found online [here](http://www.ehu.es/luis.escauriaza/apuntes_problemas_y_examene/method-of-characteristics.pdf).